# How can i find distribution of ceiling poisson

Tags: probability-distributions

There is poisson random variable $X$
$$P(X=x)=\frac{\lambda^{x}}{x!}e^{-\lambda}$$
And define random variable $Z=\lceil \beta X \rceil$  ( $\beta$ is rational number which is lower than 1).

How can i find distribution of $Z$.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with ceilings, the proper way to proceed is using probability intervals.
$$
P(Z=z)=P(z-1<\beta X <=z)=P(\frac{z-1}{\beta}<X<=\frac{z}{\beta})=F_X(\frac{z}{\beta})-F_X(\frac{z-1}{\beta})
$$
Where $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution of X. Substituting:
$$
P(Z=z)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{z}{\beta}\rfloor}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}-e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{z-1}{\beta}\rfloor}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}=
\begin{cases} 
e^{-\lambda}\sum_{i=\lfloor\frac{z-1}{\beta}\rfloor}^{\lfloor\frac{z}{\beta}\rfloor}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} &, z\ge 1 \\
e^{-\lambda} &,z=0 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible Z has value between 0 and 1?

Comment: As long as $z>\beta$, $P(Z=z)$ is strictly greater than 0. Thus, Z takes values between $(\beta\ \infty)$.

Comment: Um... i don`t understand your point. My opinion is that $Z$ have only positive integer due to ceiling function. Having only positive integer is what i want to and reason why i used ceiling function

Comment: @Kim Oops. My blame. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Kim Note however that Z can be equal to 0.

Comment: I check this distribution using matlab. But sum of all probability is not one. It is possible that i mistake. Can you check for me?